# Removing the last 6 digits from a double (Objective-C)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I get dates in the format as follows

20110626125911

They are stored in a double which works fine.

I want to remove the last 6 digits of the double, so 125911 in the example above.

Is there some handy way to always chop off those last 6 digits so as to make the double for the example above read 20110626?

I know I can do it with making the double a string and using substringtoindex etc, but its seems heavy. Just looking for maybe some nice 'trick' for this.

Many Thanks,
-Code

Comment: well u can control it through Precision

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just divide your number to 10^6 (that's 10 to the power of 6) and floor the result like this:

```
double originalDateAsDouble = 20110626125911;
double finalDateAsDouble = floor(originalDateAsDouble / pow(10, 6));
```

Let me know if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

20110626125911/100000 is what you want?

Comment: You'll want to floor that, otherwise you'll have 201106.26125911

Comment: @thegrinner I think if the number is int. is fine. no need to floor the result.

Comment: @luyuan you say "if the number is int it'll be fine" but 20110626125911 is too big to store in an int.

Comment: @thegrinner, you missed that it's integer division, lu yuan is (mostly) right

Comment: @JamesWebster so long int? long long int? :)

Comment: The question states that they are stored in a double, so try to use that. I would just suggest you floor the result.

Comment: @JamesWebster Yes, as the second answer did. Thanks for your correction:)